# RecyclerView With Wrap Content and keyboard action

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment as a bottom sheet with a title, search bar, recycler view for options and a done button below.
The recycler view must be wrapped and i have a max height for the fragment. Everything works fine. When i open keyboard and search, the adapter options get reduced and empty space will be there below the options in the container.

Now, when i close the keyboard, the the empty space is getting wrapped and height of recycler view is changed, which should not happen. The height must not be changed on keyboard actions.
**And this bug is till API 29. In API level 30, the bug is not there.**
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdoqg.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5UWi.png)  [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmx8Z.png)

The recycler view properties i used are

- height as wrap content.
- constrained height true as it is inside a constraint layout.
- setHasFixedSize(true)
- adding items in adapter with notifyItemRangeRemoved and notifyItemRangeInserted. (because notifyDataSetChanged is changing the layoutParams)

Another similar problem is mentioned here.
[RecyclerView height gets wrapped after keyboard gets closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367400/recyclerview-height-gets-wrapped-after-keyboard-gets-closed)

Comment: what if recyclerview height is match_parent?

Comment: https://medium.com/@aramaki/so-heres-the-thing-99d6d03daaf2

Comment: I want it to be wrapped based on the number of options i get at first. Hence i am using wrap_content. After that, further search or keyboard actions should not change its height whatsoever. @UsamaAltaf